# Xcode crashes when clicking on info.plist file when installing Crashlytics

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode7, crashlytics

I'm setting up Crashlytics for my app by following the instructions on [their site](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install). I have:

- Added the pods to my Podfile and installed
- Added a Run Script to my build phase

The next step is to add my API key to the info.plist file but each time I click on it it crashes. If I remove the Run Script I added Xcode runs fine. If I add the API key first then add the Run Script Xcode crashes immediately. Anybody know how to bypass this error or what I could be doing wrong?